# The span of a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra

I have what seems to be a basic question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have $X$, which is a linear vector space and hyperplane $H$. Suppose $H=M+x_0$ where $x_0 \notin M$. Then the span of $H$ is X. This seems straightforward if the dimension of X is finite since it will have dimension $n$ while the hyperplane dimension $n-1$. But, nothing guarantees that $X$ has a finite dimension.
I'd appreciate hints.

Comment: The first question to answer here is how you define a hyperplane for an infinite dimensional vector space? Possible but not directly via the dimension.

Comment: I guess $M$ is your hyperplane, not $H$ !

Comment: There isn't much difference in the infinite-dimensional case because $M$ by definition must have codimension $1$.